# Raspberry pi zero 、raspbianのimgファイルがダウンロード出来ない

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

WindowsでSDにOSを書き込みたいと思っています。
SDをフォーマットし再書き込みやHDMIでつなぐ方法、USBとWindowsをつなぐ方法を試しましたが、やはり起動出来ませんでした。

書き込み前のImgファイルを確認したところファイルが壊れていますと表示されるため、それが原因と考えました。
DLをし直してもraspbianのimgファイルが壊れており、またNOOBSを使った方法も試しましたが、NOOBSも解凍時に解凍出来ませんと表示されます。

NOOBS・img解凍時　Lhaplusの表示
os¥LibreELEC_RPi2¥LibreELCE_RPi_System.tar xz -正常に解凍出来ません。CREが一致しないか、出力先ファイルが使用中です。
このメッセージが表示されるということはダウンロードに失敗しているはずです。

・一応物は試しとこのimgを書き込み、raspberry Piを電源・ディスプレイに接続すると、ライト点滅から点灯となりますが、ライトがついても当たり前ですがディスプレイには何も表示されず。

・ダウンロードしたzipファイルのサイズがそのたびに異なります。日本のミラーサイトからもダウンロードを試しましたが同じです。

他に試すべき事があればヒントを頂戴できれば嬉しいです。

Comment: 「ダウンロードしたzipファイルのサイズがそのたびに異なります」というのはRaspberry Pi 以前の問題です。正常にダウンロードできないことには、解凍しても無意味です。最後まで正しくダウンロードが完了しているか、何回ダウンロードしてもファイルサイズが同じか、通信回線が安定しているか、そのあたりをまず確認してください。

Comment: imgのDL元はどこでしょうか。サイトによってはsha-1等が記載されていますが検証はされたのでしょうか。

Comment: ダウンロード元は公式サイトとJAISTのミラーサイトを利用させていただいております。　回線を見直し、ダウンロードサイズや解凍後のサイズはそれぞれ何度DLをしても一定に安定しました。　解凍時のエラー表示もなくなりましたが、解凍後ダブルクリックして確認すると壊れていますと表示されます。

Comment: .zip を解凍すると .img が出てくると思うのですが、何をダブルクリックしたのでしょうか？

Comment: .imgです。.imgをダブルクリックして壊れていると表示がでるかでないかで普段判断していましたが間違った方法だったのかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi用OSのzipファイルが、正しくダウンロードできて、正常に解凍できた前提でお答えします。

.imgファイルはSDカードに書き込む内容そのものです。Windowsから開くのではありません。ですので、.imgファイルをダブルクリックしてはいけません。

Windowsで.imgファイルをSDカードに書き込むには、一般的にはWin32DiskImagerというツールを使用します。

.zipファイルと、それを解凍した.imgファイル、書き込みツールであるWin32DiskImager.exeを用意すると下の図のようなります。

[image: ファイル]

Win32DiskImager.exeをダブルクリックして起動します。ファイルを開くボタンを押して、.imgファイルを選択します。書き込み先のSDカードのドライブがDeviceのところに表示されますので、確認の上、正しいドライブを選択します。

[image: Win32DiskImager]

準備ができたらWriteボタンを押します。

Comment: 私の確認方法は間違ったものだったのですね。そのまま書き込んで起動することが出来ました。なんどもお世話になり、感謝しています。

Comment: 解決して何よりです。ところで、私の回答のスクリーンショットにミスがありましたので、補足します。Win32DiskImager.exeに加えて、それに付属するいくつかの.dllファイルが必要です。それらが不足していると、「コンピューターに lib～～～.dll がないため、プログラムを開始できません。...」の様なエラーが出ますので、Win32DiskImagerをダウンロードして解凍したら、入っているファイルをひとまとめにしてフォルダに入れておきます。

Comment: さらにもう1点補足します。Win32DiskImag‌​erの現在の最新版はv1.0ですが、一部の環境で動作しない不具合があるようです。その場合、ひとつ前のv0.9.5にすると、正常に動作することがありますので、最新版が起動できなかったら、古いバージョンを試してみてください。